# How to model many-to-many database with 3 tables

Tags: python, sql, django, database, sqlite

I'm working on a django backend and I'm trying to model a database and want to do it the best practice way.
I need a "User" table, a "Portfolios" table and a "Stocks" table. A user can have multiple portfolios which consist of multiple stocks.

This is my code so far:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    in_cash = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)

class Portfolios(models.Model):
    portfolio_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock_id = models.ForeignKey("Stocks", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buy_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    number_of_shares = models.IntegerField()

class Stocks(models.Model):
    stock_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    stock_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

In my head I would have an entry in the "Portfolios" table for each stock of a portfolio.
So "Portfolios" would look like

- portfolioid 1, userid: 1, stockid: 1, buydate: 12.01.2019, shares: 20
- portfolioid 1, userid: 1, stockid: 2, buydate: 19.02.2020, shares: 41

So there is one portfolio, which contains two stocks. But overall that doesn't seem right. If used like in my example above I can't have the portfolioid as a primary key, how can I improve this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Your instinct was correct.  I think what you call a portfolio should be a position, which includes a user, a stock, and the number of shares of that stock.  Then portfolio would be the **sum** of all positions, which probably should not be a class, but rather computed in the views and displayed in the template.  The `Portfolio` thus, will not have ANY id, but the `Position`s it is made up of do.  Starting out with a good model can avoid a lot of headaches later on.  I've changed my answer.  Check to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What confused me is the name **portfolio**, which I would call **position**.  Your initial code was correct, although I changed it a bit, removing `AutoField` which is probably not needed, using a `OneToOneField` to connect a `Customer` to a `User`, removing the **s** at the end of class names, which are templates, and therefore should be singular, nor plural, adding `price` to the `Stock`.  And finally changing `Portfolio`, which should be the **sum** of all the `Position`s.

```py
from django.conf import settings

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    in_cash = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.username

class Position(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.ForeignKey('Stock', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number_of_shares = models.IntegerField()
    buy_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.customer.username + ": " + str(self.number_of_shares) + " shares of " + self.stock.stock_symbol
    
class Stock(models.Model):
    stock_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stock_symbol
```

> In my head I would have an entry in the "Portfolios" table for each
> stock of a portfolio. So "Portfolios" would look like
>
> ```
> portfolioid 1, userid: 1, stockid: 1, buydate: 12.01.2019, shares: 20
> portfolioid 1, userid: 1, stockid: 2, buydate: 19.02.2020, shares: 41
> ```
>
> So there is one portfolio, which contains two stocks. But overall that
> doesn't seem right. If used like in my example above I can't have the
> portfolioid as a primary key, how can I improve this?

You are correct, except that should be applied to a **Position**, each of which is unique, not the `Portfolio`, which is **all** the `Position`s the `Customer` has.

Comment: Again, thanks for putting that much effort into it. That works like a charm altough I think I need the portfolio kind of table. The idea is that a user can have multiple portfolios with multiple positions each so I'd need to track that. But I think I'll figure it out on my own!

Comment: Excellent!  Glad it worked, and I'm sure you will figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

As in usual many-to-many cases, you will need to create an `intermediary table` which is also called `junction table/association table`. [Associative Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)

Your users are going to have several portfolios:

```py
class UserPortfolio(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey("User")
    portfolio_id = models.ForeignKey("Portfolio")
```

The portfolios will have multiple stocks in them:

```py
class PortfolioStock(models.Model):
    portfolio_id = models.ForeignKey("Portfolio")
    stock_id = models.ForeignKey("Stock")
```

Now a user can have several portfolios, and those portfolios will include several stocks. In order to get access to the corresponding stocks for a user, you will need to join the tables.